# "Can't get Kerberos realm" on yarn cluster

Tags: kerberos, hadoop-yarn

The situation is as follows:

I'm doing this on Windows 7, with MIT Kerberos client kfw 4.0.1. I'm connecting to a YARN cluster, via OpenVPN, that is secured with Kerberos 5. This cluster has been around for a while and it's been in use by other people, so the error is not likely to be on that side of things.

I can get a ticket via kinit (returns without error). However, once I try to do any of the following commands:

- hdfs dfs -ls
- spark-shell --master yarn
- spark-submit anything --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster
- essentially any spark or hadoop command on the cluster

I get the error: Can't get Kerberos realm (or Unable to locate Kerberos realm).

My krb5.ini file is in C:\ProgramData\MIT\Kerberos5

How can I further troubleshoot this?

Comment: Just to be sure: where are you running these `kinit` and `hdfs dfs` and `spark-submit` commands -- on your Windows PC? or on a Linux box that you are connected to via VPN?

Comment: I run these on my Windows PC, which is local. This PC is connected via OpenVPN to the network I am authenticating to.

Comment: Looks like the hadoop Kerberos API cannot find the KRB5 config -- maybe they look for the Linux default `/etc/krb5.conf`?? Or they can't find any valid mapping rule in it?? ==> try `set KRB5_CONFIG=C:\ProgramData\MIT\Kerberos5\krb5.ini` before running your tests

Comment: Yes, I tested KRB5_CONFIG=C:\ProgramData\MIT\Kerberos5\krb5.ini. I had that suspicion too that it did not know where to find the config ifle. But that did not solve the problem.

Comment: Also I should mention that doing klist doesn't list my ticket... Instead it complains that it cannot find a credentials cache. Is it possible that kinit silently failed?

Comment: I never could make `kinit` work in Windows. Good luck. You may try `set KRB5CCNAME=FILE:duh.tmp` to define the cache location/protocol for all of your commands *(default cache on Windows is "API:" meaning "use IPC against MIT Kerberos service" so the service must be running and you must create the ticket in the GUI)*

Answer (score 7):

Your JVM can not locate the krb5.conf file. You have several options:

1. set JVM property: `-Djava.security.krb5.conf=/path/to/krb5.conf`
2. or put the krb5.conf file into the `<jdk-home>/jre/lib/security` folder
3. or put the krb5.conf file into the `c:\winnt\` folder

More information about locating the krb5.conf file are placed here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jgss/tutorials/KerberosReq.html

Comment: "put the krb5.conf file into the <jdk-home>/jre/lib/security folder" works for me